# Join 2 rows into one based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m fairly new to SQL and can´t get this around my head and need some help!

My table look something like this:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="307" colspan="3" valign="top">
                <p>
                    <strong>Kompetens</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    <strong>Emp.nr</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    <strong>Code</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    <strong>EndDate</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    111
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-01-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    111
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa2
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-02-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    222
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-01-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    222
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa2
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    333
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    333
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa2
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-02-02
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    444
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-01-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    444
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    Dansa2
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-02-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to merge into 1 row per employee where both Dansa1 and Dansa2 has a EndDate. Like this:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    <strong>Emp.nr</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    <strong>EndDate</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    111
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-02-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    444
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" valign="top">
                <p>
                    2015-02-01
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also use a string variable to select wich employees to include:

```css
SELECT [Emp.nr], [Code]
FROM [Kompetens]
WHERE [Emp.nr] IN @strEmp.nr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to show only rows that have both entries, dansa1 and dansa2.

You can do so with `group by`, `count` and `having`:

```
SELECT [Emp.nr], max([EndDate])
FROM [Kompetens]
GROUP BY [Emp.nr]
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Note: Like this, you don't precisely check if both rows have "Dansa1" and "Dansa2". It would also work if they had "Dansa1" twice.  with `max()`, you select only the latest date.

**Edit:**
If you have rows that e.g. have no value in the field `Code`, then you can exclude them with the `where` clause, like this:

```
SELECT [Emp.nr], max([EndDate])
FROM [Kompetens]
WHERE Code IS NOT NULL AND Code != "" 
GROUP BY [Emp.nr]
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

`Where` narrows the basis the aggregate functions are working with. `Having` narrows the result set created by the aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Still some issues though. I also get all rows where no entries have been made at all!?

Comment: Glad to help. What precisely does "no entry" mean? If it means the field `Code` is `NULL`, then you may add this condition to a `where` statement. I've edited my answer.

Comment: My bad! Turned out that all employees had an entry in the database. Just added a where statement as you suggested and got what I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: Great that it works now :-) If you would like to mark a question as resolved, then please check the green tick left to the correct answer. That way, other users will quickly understand, and the Stack Overflow statistics works correct. Then, you don't even have to add "Resolved" to the question's title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by . The query will look like :

```
SELECT [Emp.nr], [EndDate]
FROM [Kompetens]
group by [Emp.nr], [EndDate]
```

Comment: That does not solve my question i think! But maybe my understanding just is way too low!? :)